# Find and replace between two sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has been done before, but I am running into an issue in where I want to change part of this script, I just don't know how.

This is the code, below it is what I need to do.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PENCMR()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Internal NCMR
    Dim wsPE As Worksheet
    Dim wsNDA As Worksheet

    'Copy Ranges
    Dim c As Variant

    'Paste Ranges
    Dim p As Range

    'Setting Sheet
    Set wsPE = Sheets("Print-Edit NCMR")
    Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")
    Set p = wsPE.Range("A54:U54")

    With wsPE
        c = Array(.Range("AG3"), .Range("B11"), .Range("B14"), .Range("B17"), .Range("B20"), .Range("B23") _
                , .Range("Q11"), .Range("Q14"), .Range("Q17"), .Range("Q20"), .Range("R25"), .Range("V23") _
                , .Range("V25"), .Range("V27"), .Range("B32"), .Range("B36"), .Range("B40"), .Range("B44") _
                , .Range("D49"), .Range("L49"), .Range("V49"))
    End With

    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        p(i + 1).Value = c(i).Value
    Next

    With wsNDA
        Dim rFind As Long, NR As Long, LR As Long, LC As Long
        LR = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LC = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        NR = LR + 1
        rFind = wsNDA.Range("A3:A" & LR).Find(wsPE.Range("A54:U54")).Row

        .Range("A54", .Cells(2, LC)).Copy
        .Range("A" & rFind).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("A54", .Cells(1, LC)).ClearContents
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The script is meant to do this:

When the code is activated, it is meant to copy all cells and then paste them into a row below the form and then after referencing the 2nd page comparing the first cell of the newly created row to the 2nd page list copy and replace the information.

What I'd like to see, since I've been told that it can be done without pasting onto the same page, is copy the data, do a search for the ID number on the 2nd sheet, and paste over said row with the new data.

Here is the sheet:

[Excel Replace WkSht](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/Replace.zip)

The way this is written now, it doesn't replace the information, it just overwrites it with blank information. Which I've yet to figure out why... hopefully with this request rewrite, I'll be able to get that resolved.

Thanks again for the help. This place has been amazing in what they have done so far in helping me not only learn, but to write smartly in the long run.

Comment: So if the Data is for `01` then you want data to be pasted in row 3 of the 2nd sheet? and if the data is for `02`, since it is not present in Sheet2 you want to add it?

Comment: Your `Find()` looks wrong - Find() expects a value to search for, not a multi-cell range, and there are other parameters particularly `LookAt` which you really should include.  In addition, you're calling Copy and PasteSpecial on the same sheet...

Comment: Siddharth Rout, No, I want it to only replace what exists. This sheet will only update, not create new NCMRs. Tim Williams , the reason is because the only reference it needs to look for is the NCMR # on page 2. Which starts on Row 3 of page 2. Am I wrong in how I queried? As for the copy and paste on the same sheet, I know, it is one of the things I need help with. What I'd like to do is what was suggested before which was copy the data and then directly do a search for the ID on page 2, and paste onto said page

Comment: @SiddharthRout Updated notice.

Comment: @matt - what don't you like about my suggestions below?  That should work fine.

Comment: I didn't want to assume that you took into consideration what I was attempting after asking. I just wanted to know if you took what I said into consideration or not before attempting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggested changes:

```
Sub PENCMR()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Internal NCMR
    Dim wsPE As Worksheet
    Dim wsNDA As Worksheet
    Dim c As Variant 'Copy Ranges
    Dim p As Range 'Paste Ranges

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Setting Sheet
    Set wsPE = Sheets("Print-Edit NCMR")
    Set p = wsPE.Range("A54:U54")

    Set wsNDA = Sheets("NCMR Data")

    c = Array("AG3", "B11", "B14", "B17", "B20", "B23" _
            , "Q11", "Q14", "Q17", "Q20", "R25", "V23" _
            , "V25", "V27", "B32", "B36", "B40", "B44" _
            , "D49", "L49", "V49")

    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        p(i + 1).Value = wsPE.Range(c(i)).Value
    Next

    With wsNDA
        Dim NR As Long, LR As Long, LC As Long
        Dim f As Range

        LR = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LC = .Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        NR = LR + 1

        'find matching row if it exists
        Set f = .Range("A3:A" & LR).Find(what:=p.Cells(1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Resize(1, p.Cells.Count).Value = p.Value
        Else
            'what should happen if not found?
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've checked out the script, and attempted it.  The script doesn't come back with an error, but it doesn't update the field in NCMR Data. The problem I am having right now is that there will never be a time if something isn't found because the list the form pulls from will either show data if there are any NCMRs or none if there are not.

Comment: Ignore my (now deleted) earlier comment.  Applying the same zero-padding format to A54 on the PE sheet fixed it for me. Need to ensure that what's being searched for is in the same format as your list of ID's.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just need to know, do I really need to add in code if something wasn't found? Because the way the script was designed on the page as per the link shows what I had in mind. Nothing will ever show up that is not there.

Comment: If that's the case then no you don't really need any code to deal with it. However, I would strongly suggest at least putting in a Msgbox alert to let you know if for any reason the id was not found (eg. someone hand-edited the Data sheet). Otherwise it's just going to silently fail.

Comment: If someone edits the list, the way it's designed it would automatically populate with the change wouldn't it? At least I thought it would with the way I designed it.

Comment: Well in this case, it failed. I don't know why...it moved everything, but it didn't transfer the changes over.

Comment: I'm not clear on how your current design (where the edit page is linked to the data sheet with formulas) is going to allow you to edit a record: when you enter a new value you have to overwrite the formula.  As for what works or not, if you contact me directly (Tim j williams no spaces at gmail dot com) I'll send you my version.